# How to use select query for counting number of attributes in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a table with `menu_id` is a primary key. I want to run a select sql query want result as `service_id` and count of `service_id`. In this table we are using two `service_id`: S101,S102. So  query should return S101, S102, 6, 1. The first two is `service_id` and other two are count of `service_id`. Below is the table:

[image]

Please suggest me the the query for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT service_id,COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY service_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY clause.

Here's a [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) to the usage of GROUP BY.

Query: select service_id, COUNT(*) from table_name GROUP BY service_id

A google search would have done the job.